# Beginner Question: cannot reference an identifier before its definition

Tags: racket

Why is the following code throwing cannot reference an identifier before its definition?

```lisp
(require pict)

(define uyy
    (let ([p (filled-rectangle 50 50)]
          [q (hc-append p p)])
      (vc-append q q)))
```

```
p: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
  in module: top-level
```

However, this runs fine

```lisp
(define (checker-element size)
    (let
        ([r (colorize (square size) "red")]
        [b (colorize (square size) "black")]
        [l1  (hc-append r b)]
        [l2  (hc-append b r)])
        (vc-append l1 l2)))
```

I think both should be using `let*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`let*`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html?q=let*#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._let%2A%29%29) instead of [`let`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html?q=let*#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._let%29%29) to have the second binding in the scope of the first.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. However, I edited the question with another code block which I think should also be using `let*`  but that runs fine.

Comment: Yes, the `r` argument in the `l1` clause does no know about `r` defined in the first clause. So it should be unbound unless defined outside the function

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.